# Why pandas to_excel function has error encode sometimes?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the code

```py
import pandas as pd

error_code_link_lst = []
error_code_link_lst.append('twdJK7dzQR_x298_x298_x49147_x')
error_code_link_lst.append('1665207170810_x828_x1470_x745770_x.jpg')  # _x1470_     ᑰ
error_code_link_lst.append('h4fdn32sjG_x593_x593_x199560_x')
error_code_link_lst.append('xEQpZ7JjkZ_x288_x288_x3108_x')            # _x3108_     ㄈ
error_code_link_lst.append('SGkZYZKCRR_x298_x298_x49147_x')

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['link'] = [i for i in error_code_link_lst]
for i in df['link']:
    print(i)
df.to_excel('error.xlsx', index=None)
```

Output in terminal is right:

```
twdJK7dzQR_x298_x298_x49147_x
1665207170810_x828_x1470_x745770_x.jpg
h4fdn32sjG_x593_x593_x199560_x
xEQpZ7JjkZ_x288_x288_x3108_x
SGkZYZKCRR_x298_x298_x49147_x
```

But in the `xlsx` file, it looks like in a wrong encoding

| link |
| --- |
| twdJK7dzQR_x298_x298_x49147_x |
| 1665207170810_x828ᑰx745770_x.jpg |
| h4fdn32sjG_x593_x593_x199560_x |
| xEQpZ7JjkZ_x288_x288ㄈx |
| SGkZYZKCRR_x298_x298_x49147_x |

It seems like `_x1470_` -> `ᑰ` and `_x3108_` -> `ㄈ`.

> I try to use `df.to_excel('error.xlsx', index=None, encoding='utf-8')`, but it not works as well.
>
> I wonder why and how can I get the right data. Thanks!

Comment: For me it saving absolutely fine

Comment: once write to text file & check if you get same outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `encoding='utf8'` as parameter in to_excel function.
[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRMSR.png)

Comment: I have tryed both `encoding='utf8'` and `encoding='utf-8'`, it not works.

Comment: Did you get the same encoding issue when you load that xlsx file again with pandas?

Comment: Yes, the content of xlsx file is the same.

Comment: i do not find any issue, i have opened the file in Excel it works well for me. i have added the screenshot in the answer.

Comment: That's embarrassing, anyway, thanks.

Comment: Just try to change encoding of the file in your MS excel, it will probably able to decode it well. Welcome:)